# gdm3 or lighdm not working (X11 won't start)

Tags: debian, x11, lxde, lightdm, gdm

I am using Debian 9. After installing Gnome I only see my mouse cursor on my computer screen. I uninstalled Gnome and enabled X11 but it didn't work. I need to connect to the board I use via ssh and type

```
> startx
```

in order to get an image on the screen. I may have messed something up while installing gnome.

**Update:**

`apt install gdm` is not working:

```
root@linaro-alip:~# apt install gdm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package gdm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is
only available from another source However the following packages replace
it:   libgdm1 cinnamon-control-center-data
E: Package 'gdm' has no installation candidate
```

**Update 2:**

`dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` >> I manually selected lightdm

```
root@linaro-alip:~# systemctl enable lightdm
```

```
Synchronizing state of lightdm.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable lightdm
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).
This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some
   instance name specified.
```

The problem is still not fixed.

When I use the below command it says the file does not exist. How can I fix this?

`update-rc.d '/etc/init.d/xserver start' defaults`

```
update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/xserver start
```

Comment: Hello did you ever fix this issue? I'm facing the same problem.

Comment: Is your problem exactly the same as mine?

Comment: no, not exactly, but very similar.

Comment: I don't remember exactly as I encountered this error a long time ago, but I do remember uninstalling gnome and reinstalling lightdm. If you can give more details about your problem, maybe I can help more.

Comment: I see, thank you. this is what's actually happening in my case: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/729539/debian-bullseye-rdp-vnc-blank-scree-or-oh-no-something-went-wrong-issue

Comment: I've looked into your problem and researched but couldn't get any results. What I can suggest to you is to stop the service by saying ```systemctl stop gdm``` (or whatever you are using) via ```tty2 terminal```, delete everything about gnome and reinstall it. Before doing ```tty f1``` you need to make sure you start the service. You can use ```systemctl start service_name``` to start it. You'll also need to run `systemctl enable service_name` for it to start automatically every time the system starts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can start the graphical environment manually you are likely missing a graphical login screen (in Gnome systems usually GDM), or it is not being started automatically.

Please try to install and enable it, by executing as `root` (prefix by `sudo` as appropriate):

```
apt install gdm
```

If the `apt install` command tells you that `gdm` is already installed, leave it and proceed to the other commands.

If the command tells you that the package `gdm` is not available, try `lightdm` instead:

```
apt install lightdm
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

Then enable and start `gdm` (or `lightdm`, replace as appropriate):

```
systemctl enable gdm
systemctl start gdm
```

If these commands work then the login will start.  Open a console (or go back) then please enter (`root` again):

```
systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

to enable the graphical login upon boot.

If the `systemctl start gdm` command fails (no login screen appears) then re-install gnome itself first:

```
apt install --reinstall gnome
```

and proceed to the next command in line.

Comment: `apt install gdm` not working.

`root@linaro-alip:~# apt install gdm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package gdm is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgdm1 cinnamon-control-center-data

E: Package 'gdm' has no installation candidate`

Comment: @Buket Added an option for `lightdm`, q.v.

Comment: There is no image to see. I have attached the outputs of the commands.

Comment: OK, I have looked at it and I am thinking. Perhaps Debian does not like the `systemctl` (sorry, I don't use Debian and do not know it). It may not be needed then. Does `systemctl set-default graphical.target` work, though? Then after reboot it could just be fine.

Comment: I tried again but it still didn't work. If there was something broken, I think it wouldn't run in the `startx` command. I can't understand where I went wrong. Thanks for your help.